# Почему при 100% ширине блок не на весь экран?

Tags: html, css

Я заметил одну странную особенность [Даже страницу для демонстрации сделал.](http://plitka20x20.h1n.ru/test.html) Если открыть панель *инструменты разработчика* (F12) и вызвать показ мобильных устройств 
(Ctrl + Shift + M)то: чёрный блок которому задано width:100% не растягивается во всю ширину. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за фиксированной длины красной полосы.. При ее отключении все ок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно стоит использовать медиа-запросы или изменить CSS... (например, использовать `max-width`).

Comment: Вот и я негодую почему браузер не сделает полосу горизонтальной прокрутки, вместо того чтобы помещать блок с фиксированной шириной? Ведь ключевое свойство здесь width:100% у чёрного, он полюбому должен быть на всю ширину. И ещё... если на компе размер уменьшить то всё нормально. А если с планшета, то такая ересь

Answer (score 0):

У тебя для body стоит `margin: 8px;`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто интересно, кто поставил -? 
Вопрос был, я на него ответил, в чем проблема?

Comment: ответ не верный.. видно по скрину что смотрели в десктопном варианте, а не мобильном - плохо прочитали вопрос